# make a link in angular custom filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have make a custom filter in angular to  first extract this pattern **@[1:abc]** from a string into  into abc.Here is my code

**Html :**

```
<div class="mts mbs lg-feed-content-txt" hm-read-more hm-limit="200" hm-more-text="more" hm-less-text="less" hm-dots-class="toggle-dots-grey" hm-text="{{activity.post.text | mentionParser:activity.post}}" hm-link-class="toggle-readmore"></div>
```

**Javasctipt**:

```
.filter('mentionParser', function() {
    return function(text, res) {
        var text;
        var regex = /[@[0-9]+[:]([a-z|A-Z ]+)]/g;
        var idSeprator = /[0-9]+/g;
        var displaySeprator = /([a-z|A-Z ]+)/g;
        var pattern = text.match(regex);
        var uidList = [];
        var textCopy = text;
        var mentions = [];

        if (pattern != null) {
            for (var j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++) {
                var name ='<a>'+ res.mentionList[j].name +'</a>';
                textCopy = textCopy.replace(pattern[j], name );
            }
            return textCopy;

        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
});
```

What i want is that to make **abc** name linkable